# Using a --experimental-loader=loader.mjs like syntax for use in import syntax of ES script module

Tags: javascript, html, import, browser, module

I am using a `--experimental-loader` in node.js for a .mjs file. The command looks something like this:

`node --experimental-loader=./loader.mjs ./demo.mjs`

I wish to use the loader in the browser that supports import statement inside a ES script module `<script type="module"></script>`. The loader basically has a small modification.

```
<script type="module">

<!-- Need a loader to load before this like node.js -->
import { default as x } from "./bundle.js";

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The loader can be used in the browser by adding a type="module" attribute to the script tag, as follows:

```
<script type="module" src="./loader.mjs"></script>
```

This will tell the browser to use the loader for any subsequent import statements in the script.

Comment: You mean something like this: `<script type="module" src="loader.mjs"> <!-- Need a loader to load before this like node.js --> import { default as x } from "./bundle.js"; </script>`

Comment: @Gary You cannot combine both an `src` attribute and module code into the same `<script>` tag. See [What does a script-Tag with src AND content mean?](/q/6528325/4642212).

Comment: Ok. I need to load a `loader.mjs` like I use with `--experimental-loader=./loader.mjs`. Any help with that? Is it even possible?